# Convert HEX to Decimal value? w/ an example

Tags: decimal, hex

My professor has assured me this example is correct but I can not back into it. I need to convert the mac of my printer to decimal so I can find the decimal value.

In the example he gave me, I have tried this on several online converters and I can not replicate it. What am I missing here, I searched stack I see some examples but I can not reproduce this so this is no duplicate.

MAC = AA:BB:CC:00:11:22, converted to decimal would be 170.187.204.0.17.34

Comment: I am using http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ and just copying and pasting and I get 1.87723558163E+14!

Comment: you have to do the individual segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mac address has a size of 6 byte. This bytes are seperated by colons.

To convert the mac address to decimal you have to convert these single bytes.
So hex AA would be 140 decimal, BB=187 and CC=204 and so on...

Comment: That was my mistake!!!! Thought that I can drop the entire thing in a converter, did not think I had to do on each nibble. This site also helped http://www.ehow.com/how_6184225_calculate-mac-address-binary.html

Answer (score 0):

A MAC address has six **groups** of two hexadecimal digits. In this case you can think of ':' as periods to make it easier. So if MAC = AA:BB:CC:00:11:22 = AA.BB.CC.00.11.22 you'll separately convert each of the six hexadecimal groups to decimal form.

When converting from hex to decimal, I like to use exponential notation so I know I'm getting the right answer. After some practice, you pick it up can can do the conversions on sight.

(2nd digit x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (1st digit × 16<sup>0</sup>)

So starting from the right of the address, going through
AA.BB.CC.00.11.22<sub>hex</sub> group by group looks like:

a.b.c.d.e.f

Remember:
A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, F = 15

a.
(10 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (10 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 170<sub>dec</sub>

b.
(11 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (11 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 187<sub>dec</sub>

c.
(12 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (12 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 204<sub>dec</sub>

d.
(0 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (0 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 0<sub>dec</sub>

e.
(1 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (1 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 17<sub>dec</sub>

f.
(2 x 16<sup>1</sup>) + (2 × 16<sup>0</sup>) = 34<sub>dec</sub>

So **AA:BB:CC:00:11:22 = 170.187.204.0.17.34**