# Convert decimal MAC address into hexadecimal MAC address

Tags: excel, hex, excel-formula, decimal

I have been searching for a method to convert a decimal MAC address into a hex one.

So for example  `170.187.204.0.17.34`  to  `AA:BB:CC:00:11:22`.

Credits goes to [Convert HEX to Decimal value? w/ an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079830/convert-hex-to-decimal-value-w-an-example).

I put my decimal value into columnA (starting A2) and the hexadecimal equivalent should go into columnB (starting B2).

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

With `170.187.204.0.17.34` in A1, apply Text to Columns with `.` as the delimiter. In A2 copied across to F2:

```
=DEC2HEX(A1)
```

in G2:  `=A2&":"&B2&":"&C2&":"&D2&":"&E2&":"&F2`

Or, in B2 and dealing with hex for `0`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(DEC2HEX(MID(A2,1,FIND(".",A2)-1))&":"&DEC2HEX(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),1,FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))-1))&":"&DEC2HEX(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),1,FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))-1))&":"&DEC2HEX(MID(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),1,FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))-1))&":"&DEC2HEX(MID(MID(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),1,FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))-1))&":"&DEC2HEX(MID(MID(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)),FIND(".",MID(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)),FIND(".",MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN($A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2)))+1,LEN(A2))),":0:",":00:")
```

Comment: Thanks! you had a typo in the G2: line:
=A2&":"&B2&":"&C2&":"&D2&":"&E2&":"&F2
I guess it should be :)

Comment: Hi pnuts, this second solution is working perfectly! Exactly what I needed. Sorry if I didnt make it clear in the first post. Thanks

Comment: Respect for this long formula, but somehow it doesn't for other addresses, e.g. 8.32.0.171.205.239 should return, 08:20:00:AB:CD:EF

I get 8:20:00:47:AB:CD I guess it is some zero padding and for the last 3 groups I dont know why seems like AB is at the wrong place and 47? hmm

any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Sorry I haven't got back to you, I just checked the updated formular and it seems promising :)

Answer (score 1):

As much as I enjoyed reading through @pnuts ' code, this may be a simpler solution:

```
=DEC2HEX(MID(A2,1,3),2)&":"&
 DEC2HEX(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","^",1))+1,3),2)&":"&
 DEC2HEX(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","^",2))+1,3),2)&":"&
 DEC2HEX(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","^",3))+1,3),2)&":"&
 DEC2HEX(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","^",4))+1,3),2)&":"&
 DEC2HEX(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","^",5))+1,3),2)
```

Line one takes advantage of the fact that `DEC2HEX` truncates its parameter:

- Given 170.187.204.0.17.34, `MID` returns 170, which is already an integer.
- Given 1.9.1.1.1.1, `MID` returns 1.9, which `DEC2HEX` truncates to 1.

Lines two through six `SUBSTITUTE` the nth "." with "^" and then `FIND` that character, returning the next 3 characters.  Given 170.187.204.0.17.34, these `MID` functions return:

- 187
- 204
- 0.1
- 17.
- 34

These are then fed to `DEC2HEX`.

And we simply concatenate everything with colons.

Output:  `AA:BB:CC:00:11:22`

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for a detailed explanation! It works just like I wanted it to. I have a question though, mac-address is 12 characters long, e.g. 8.32.0.171.205.239 returns: 08:20:00:AB:CD:EF
just like I wanted it to, im not sure about the zero padding, I mean what mac-address (in hex value) is correct?
08:20:00:AB:CD:EF
or
8:20:0:AB:CD:EF

Thank you!

Comment: Last, is there any chances to turn this into a macro somehow?

Comment: Making this a function is more difficult than I thought, because using `DEC2HEX` gives "Sub or Function not defined" within VBA.  @pnuts is the VBA expert, so he might have a work-around.

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, got exatly what you got. :/ I will wait till he answers