# How to convert decimal to hex and placing colon in excel

Tags: excel

I have on column with MAC address in Decimal format which needs to be converted to Hexadecimal format.

For example - I have value as `0000458721345758` in decimal format
where I need to convert them to hexadecimal in the format as `00:B9:D5:76:F5`.

Please help me out.

Comment: If you are doing this in Excel, why the SQL tag?

Comment: so basically `0000458721345758` will become `6A:CD:EC:40:DE`? right now i dont know your formula to get `00:B9:D5:76:F5`

Comment: It will not become like that I just need the format like that,Even I don't know answer for that.but I gave an example

Comment: do you ned to know how to convert `DEC 2 HEX` or to show your HEX as `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`?

Comment: All of my MAC addresses have 6 hexadecimals, not 5.

Comment: yes I am sorry I need to know for 6 hexadecimals and having zeroes infront of my decimal format.

Comment: I have the value in Decimal format as 00000000048121333040,need to convert it into hex with colons

Answer (score 0):

I think the hexadecimal equivalent of `0000458721345758` in decimal format is `6A:CD:EC:40:DE` (if it isn't and you don't know otherwise perhaps it does not matter).

With the former in A1 this formula:

```
=IF(MOD(LEN(DEC2HEX(A1)),2)=1,"0"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),1,1)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),2,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),4,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),6,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),8,2),MID(DEC2HEX(A1),1,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),3,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),5,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),7,2)&":"&MID(DEC2HEX(A1),9,2))
```

returns `0B:34:41:45:30` and something similar for decimal numbers roughly between -5.5E+11 and 5.5E+11 (subject to left-alignment of low decimal numbers).

For `00000000048121333040` the output is `0B:34:41:45:30`.

However I find it difficult imagine any use for the above and speculate that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814863/convert-decimal-mac-address-into-hexadecimal-mac-address) may be more useful.